# Using find + grep + awk in combination

Tags: awk, grep, find

I'd need to filter through a list files (output of top command) for some info:

- Firstly I need to list files with a find
- Then, I need to grep for lines with a pattern
- Finally, I need to pickup one column I'm interested into.

Seems I'm unable to bind the find with both grep and awk:

My first attempt:

```
find . -name "high-cpu.out" -exec grep "jboss" | awk '{ print $5 }' {} \;

find: missing argument to `-exec'
awk: fatal: cannot open file `{}' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Second attempt:

```
find . -name "high-cpu.out" -exec grep "jboss" {} \ | awk '{ print $5 }';

find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using AWK to match the pattern instead of `grep`:

```
find . -name "high-cpu.out" -exec awk '/jboss/ { print $5 }' {} +
```

This also allows the use of the `+` variant of `-exec`, resulting in fewer `awk` invocations.

When you tried

```
find . -name "high-cpu.out" -exec grep "jboss" | awk '{ print $5 }' {} \;
```

the shell processed the pipe first, not `find`. That led to `find` failing with “missing argument to ‘-exec’”: `{} \;` wasn’t included in the arguments passed to it (they were passed to `awk`).

Your second attempt failed because `find` couldn’t see the closing semi-colon since it wasn’t separated from the `awk` argument. In any case the pipe wouldn’t have worked, since `find` doesn’t delegate to the shell.

Answer (score 0):

> find . -name "high-cpu.out" -exec grep "jboss" | awk '{ print $5 }' {}
> ;
>
> find: missing argument to `-exec' awk: fatal: cannot open file` {}'
> for reading (No such file or directory)

This cannot work until the exec command is broken/finished at the "|" level so {} cannot be interpreted by the awk sub-command.

so you have to do

```
.......  -exec awk '/pattern/ {operation}' {} +
```

or

```
 find . -name "high-cpu.out" -exec grep pattern {} \; | awk '{operation}'
```

but it is never a good idea to use many commands sed+awk+grep for the same work ; You have to choose one of them & adapt the regexp on pattern to match your needs